# Single form deals with 2 models

Tags: yii

I have created two models :User and UserProfile , Now I want display in some fields of UserProfile in User view (_form) ,  on create action in user table I have done this  :

```
  public function actionCreate() {



    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    $user_form= new TblUser;
    $profile_form = new TblUserProfile;

            if(isset($_POST['user_form'], $_POST['profile_form'])){



     // populate input data to $a and $b
    $user_form->attributes=$_POST['user_form'];
    $profile_form->attributes=$_POST['profile_form'];


           // validate BOTH $a and $b
          $valid=$user_form->validate();
         $valid=$profile_form->validate() && $valid;



        if($valid)
    {
        // use false parameter to disable validation
        $user_form->save(false);


         $profile_form->save(false);
            // ...redirect to another page


        }
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'user_form'=>$user_form,
        'profile_form'=>$profile_form,
    ));

}
```

Then ,

This is my _form class of user table

```
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo Chtml::errorSummary($user_form,$profile_form); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->hiddenField($user_form,'id'); ?> 
        <?php //echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($user_form,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($user_form,'password',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>40)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($user_form,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($user_form,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($user_form,'username',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php // echo $form->error($user_form,'username'); ?>
    </div>

            <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'Is_active'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->HiddenField($user_form,'Is_active'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->error($model,'Is_active'); ?>
    </div>


        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($profile_form,'user_first_name '); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($profile_form,'user_first_name ',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php  echo $form->error($profile_form,'user_first_name '); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($user_form->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>


        <!-- form -->
```

Now , I have render both models in same view like this ,

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', 
    array('user_form'=>$user_form,'profile_form'=>$profile_form)); ?>
```

Problem which I am facing after doing all this is :

```
 Undefined variable: form

C:\wamp\www\topicoll\protected\views\tblUser\_form.php(9)

01 
02 
03 <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
04 
05 
06 
07     <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
08 
09     <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($user_form,$profile_form); ?>
10 
11     <div class="row">
12         <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>
13         <?php echo $form->hiddenField($user_form,'id'); ?> 
14         <?php //echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
15     </div>
16 
17     <div class="row">
18         <?php echo $form->labelEx($user_form,'password'); ?>
19         <?php echo $form->passwordField($user_form,'password',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>40)); ?>
20         <?php echo $form->error($user_form,'password'); ?>
21     </div>
```

Please tell me what I am missing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh.. you are using  CHtml to start a form `CHtml::beginForm()`  and to end `CHtml::endForm()`

if you do so, you have to use CHtml to generate form elements as well i.e. `CHtml::activeTextfield($model, 'field', array())`  and  `CHtml::activeLabelEx($model, 'field')`  in all all places in your _form

other way is...

add this code instead of CHtml::beginForm().

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    ),
));
```

and add this code in place of CHtml::endForm()

```
$this->endWidget();
```

it will fix your problem.

Comment: Ok , Now I got this error :   Property "TblUserProfile.user_first_name " is not defined.

Comment: user_first_name is the attribute of model UserProfile

Comment: your model naming seems wrong ... what is your model class name ?  

is it `class User`  or `class TblUser`  ??

is it `class UserProfile`  or `class TblUserProfile`  ??

`
$user_form= new User;
$profile_form = new UserProfile;
`

Comment: Now ,I have used **CHTML** to generate form elements but above error occured

Comment: TblUserProfile and TblUser are model class names

Comment: please remove the extra space in field name `'user_first_name '`  i.e.  `($profile_form,'user_first_name ')`

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)

I have more question Now my submit button is not working .


<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($user_form->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>


Additionally I want to know which model I will pass to submitbutton ??

Answer (score 1):

In your _form.php replace `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>` with

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'profile-form',
    'type'=>'horizontal',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
```

and `<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>` with

```
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And in your controller change the code block

```
if(isset($_POST['user_form'], $_POST['profile_form'])){



     // populate input data to $a and $b
    $user_form->attributes=$_POST['user_form'];
    $profile_form->attributes=$_POST['profile_form'];
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['TblUserProfile'], $_POST['TblUser'])){



     // populate input data to $a and $b
    $user_form->attributes=$_POST['TblUser'];
    $profile_form->attributes=$_POST['TblUserProfile'];
```

Comment: @dlnGd0nG What is the difference  ?

Comment: @ShumailaKhan What difference? I dint understand what you asking

Comment: As You have mentioned above , use of object instead of there variable ( like user_form , profile_form ) , So what is the difference between this use

Comment: You must specify the model class name in `$_POST` array as yii generates the html `name` attribute in the form prefixed with model classname. So `$_POST['profile_form']` will not work. Look at the generated html for clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'profile-form',
    'type'=>'horizontal',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
and <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?> with

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
And in your controller change the code block

if(isset($_POST['user_form'], $_POST['profile_form'])){



     // populate input data to $a and $b
    $user_form->attributes=$_POST['user_form'];`enter code here`
    $profile_form->attributes=$_POST['profile_form'];
with
```